# How to format Date from QString in QML

Tags: qt

I am using QML Calendar and would like to set property of maximumDate and minimumDate.

According to the documentation

*By default, this property is set to the latest maximum date (25 October, 275759 AD)*

so I made an API that returns me this date in string format "25 October, 2018 AD"

when i try set

```
 maximumDate = "25 October, 2018 AD"
```

QML throws me an error that i cannot assign QString to QDateTime

My question is how do format this string to date inorder for maximumDate to accept it. I was hoping to do it only in QML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion between a string and `QDate`, there is however one that works bidirectionally for `QDate` and qml's `Date`.

However, it doesn't seem like dates work with the format you are trying to use. I think you are confusing the stated date value as a literal value, when in fact it is just a human readable date.

So instead, you should try this:

```
maximumDate = Date.fromLocaleString(Qt.locale(), "2018-10-25", "yyyy-mm-dd")
```